# PHP multidimensional arrays accessing function

Tags: php, html, function, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to implement a function for multiplying two numeric multidimensional arrays, I performed three cycles to iterate over the rows and columns of corresponding. However something is failing there.

The **PHP** is just **not generating any web page**, whenever I comment the function code and the function calling it fails...

```
function multiplicaMatriz($matrix1, $matrix2){

    $ab = 0;

    echo "<table border="1">";
        for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
            echo "<tr>";
            for($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
                $ab = 0;
                for($k = 0; $k < 3; $k++) {
                    $ab += (($matrix1[$i][$k])*($matrix2[$k][$j]));
                }
                echo "<td>".$ab."</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Rest of my code is here:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        Novatos del PHP
        </title>
    </head>

    <body> <center>



    <?php


        $m1 = array (   array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
                        array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
                        array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
                        //array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100))
                    );


        $m2 = array (   array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
                        array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
                        array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
                        //array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100))
                    );

        function imprimeMatriz($matrix){
            echo "<table width=\"200\" border=\"1\">";

            foreach($matrix as $row =>$rValue){
                echo "<tr>";
                foreach($rValue as $col =>$cValue){
                    echo "<td>".$cValue."</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }

        function sumaMatriz($matrix1, $matrix2){
                echo "<table width=\"200\" border=\"1\">";

                foreach($matrix1 as $row1 =>$rValue1){
                        echo "<tr>";
                        foreach($rValue1 as $col1 =>$cValue1)
                                echo "<td>".($cValue1+$matrix2[$row1][$col1])."</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
        }

        function multiplicaMatriz($matrix1, $matrix2){

            $ab = 0;

            echo "<table border="1">";
                for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    for($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
                        $ab = 0;
                        for($k = 0; $k < 3; $k++) {
                            $ab += (($matrix1[$i][$k])*($matrix2[$k][$j]));
                        }
                        echo "<td>".$ab."</td>";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            echo "</table>";
        }       


        print "<h2>Matriz 1</h2>";
        imprimeMatriz($m1);

        print "<br>";

        print "<h2>Matriz 2</h2>";
        imprimeMatriz($m2);

        print "<br>";

        print "<h2>Suma de matrices</h2>";
        sumaMatriz($m1, $m2);

        print "<br>";

        print "<h2>Suma de matrices</h2>";
        multiplicaMatriz($m1, $m2);

    ?>


     </center> </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? The lack of a displayed web page is probably due to something elsewhere in the code.

Comment: I just posted it, @StephenTG

Comment: So if you cut out all the php, the page displays fine? (albeit with just a title). I just want to make sure it's somehow an issue with the function

Comment: Yes, it's a function issue.

Comment: Well, I'm stumped. Can you try just including one function at a time, see if there's only one that's causing an issue. I can't see what would be wrong, but it might narrow things down a bit

Comment: How one function at a time? Well I really checked it with out the function and the calling and it generates the two m-dimension arrays, prints them, sums them to print the sum.

Comment: Answers are given, all works fine:) You just need to switch your display_errors ON, it'll show you this simple mistakes in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to escape the `"` on line 57.  You probably want to turn on some error reporting so that you get some idea about what is causing the failure :)

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

To fix the code, change:

```
echo "<table border="1">";
```

to:

```
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
```

Comment: If you turn on error reporting (adding that line at the top of your script), then you will see the error on the page. Alternatively, if you can't get it to work, you could drop it all into a `try...catch` block and print out the errors your self. [php error handling docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Answer (score 2):

Diego, of it's your real code, byte-to-byte, you just need to copy it to some PHP IDE, and you'll see what is the problem.

```
function multiplicaMatriz($matrix1, $matrix2){
    $ab = 0;
    echo "<table border="1">"; // <-- Look here, you messed up your quotes
```